# Cannot find name 'firebase'.ts(2304)

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to use typescript to create a Firebase app. How do I import firebase into script.ts?

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>App</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.3/firebase.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

script.ts (I get: Cannot find name 'firebase'.ts(2304)):

```
firebase.initializeApp(...)
```

UPDATE

I used this info: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart

Installed `npm install firebase@5.8.0 --save`

then in script.ts I have:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase'
firebase.initializeApp({...})
const db = firebase.firestore()
db.collection('users').get().then((querySnapshot) => {
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    console.log(`${doc.id} => ${doc.data()}`)
  })
})
```

On the browser I get this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
    at script.js:2`
I don't know how to make typescript work on the client. I use VSCode.

UPDATE:

Problem solved. This is the solution:

```
/// <reference path="./node_modules/firebase/index.d.ts" />

firebase.initializeApp({...})
const db = firebase.firestore()
```

Answer (score -1):

This should help you get started. It shows how to use TS and Firebase together. I found this by searching the Firebase docs for using it with TypeScript. [Firebase GitHub TypeScript Starter](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/typescript-getting-started)

Comment: That part is on the server, I know that well. I am interested on the client side.